# The spark driver has stopped unexpectedly and is restarting. Your notebook will be automatically reattached

Tags: excel, scala, apache-spark, azure-databricks

I try to analyze a dataset of 500Mb in Databricks. These data are stored in Excel file. The first thing that I did was to install Spark Excel package `com.crealytics.spark.excel` from Maven (last version - 0.11.1).

These are the parameters of the cluster:

[image]

Then I executed the following code in Scala notebook:

```
val df_spc = spark.read
          .format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
          .option("useHeader", "true")
          .load("dbfs:/FileStore/tables/test.xlsx")
```

But I got error about the Java heap size and then I get another error "java.io.IOException: GC overhead limit exceeded". Then I executed this code again and got another error after 5 minutes running:

> The spark driver has stopped unexpectedly and is restarting. Your
>   notebook will be automatically reattached.

I do not understand why it happens. In fact the data set is quite small for the distributed computing and the cluster size should be ok to process these data. What should I check to solve it?

Comment: This source is not even remotely distributed. It will read the data locally on the driver, then it parallelize. That's as inefficient as it gets, and creates multiple copies of the data at some point. If your data is as small then using Spark doesn't make any sense anyway. If it is not, I'd suggest you do yourself a favor and switch to format that is actually suitable for large scale analytics. That being said, tuning (and increasing) available memory should do the trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also got stuck in same situation where i am unable to process my 35000 record xlsx file.
Below solutions I tried to work around:

1. With the free **azure subscription** and **14 day pay as you go** mode, you can process xlsx with less number of records.In my case with trial version, I have to change it to 25 records.
2. Also downgrade the worker type to **Standard_F4S 8GB Memory 4core, 0.5DBU, 1 worker** configuration.
3. Added below options:

   sqlContext.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").
   option("location","filename here...").option("useHeader","true").option("treatEmptyValueAsNulls","true").option("maxRowsInMemory",20).option("inferSchema","true").load("filename here...")

Comment: .....`option("treatEmptyValueAsNulls","true").option("maxRowsInMemory",20)`..... solved for me!

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue. We reached out to DataBricks, who provided us this answer
"In the past we were able to address this issue by simply restarting a cluster that has been up for a long period of time.
This issue occurs due the fact that JVMs reuse the memory locations too many times and start misbehaving."